# Loki AppCenter is listing all apps as uninstalled

Tags: updates, appcenter

Congrats on a great and simple distro. After install of Loki I downloaded a bunch of apps no problem One day later the AppCenter shows everything as uninstalled ( they are installed and mostly working) However that means I ca't download anything else because it wants to install all apps when I press install for any app I did however managed to install aan app using terminal.

Comment: same here... its to sad for this distro to have that app center, pls devs remove it and atleast put the gnome software center...

Comment: Any idea to repair this problem? Freya has been more frendly, Loki creates only problems.